# Calling Module32First Gives Invalid Parameter (Error Code 87)

Tags: java, jna

I am using JNA and writing some code to enumerate through all of the modules available in a process. I successfully obtain the snapshot handle via CreateToolhelp32Snapshot, however on my first Module32First call, I am getting error code 87 for "Invalid Parameter".

Below is the relevant code that I am using:

Code in question:

```
   private void getModule() {
        Pointer hSnapshot = this.kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(WinAPI.TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, this.processId);

        if(hSnapshot != null) {
            WinAPI.MODULEENTRY32 moduleEntry32 = new WinAPI.MODULEENTRY32();

            moduleEntry32.write(); // Write the struct in memory (for dwSize to be registered)

            Pointer moduleEntry32Pointer = moduleEntry32.getPointer();

            if(this.kernel32.Module32First(hSnapshot, moduleEntry32Pointer)) {
                 // irrelevant stuff here
            }
        }

        System.out.println(this.kernel32.GetLastError()); // Prints out "87"

        this.kernel32.CloseHandle(hSnapshot);

    }
```

Kernel32 Mapper Class:

```
    Pointer CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(int dwFlags, int th32ProcessID);

    boolean Module32First(Pointer hSnapshot, Pointer lpme);

    boolean Module32Next(Pointer hSnapshot, Pointer lpme);
```

ModuleEntry32 Structure:

```
    public static class MODULEENTRY32 extends Structure {
        public int dwSize = this.size();
        public int th32ModuleID;
        public int th32ProcessID;
        public int GlblcntUsage;
        public int ProccntUsage;
        public Pointer modBaseAddr;
        public int modBaseSize;
        public Pointer hModule;
        public String szModule;
        public String szExePath;

        public MODULEENTRY32() {
            super();
        }

        public MODULEENTRY32(Pointer p) {
            super(p);
        }

        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList(new String[] {"dwSize", "th32ModuleID", "th32ProcessID", "GlblcntUsage", "ProccntUsage", "modBaseAddr", "modBaseSize", "hModule", "szModule", "szExePath"});
        }
    }
```

And finally, this is "WinAPI.TH32CS_SNAPMODULE":

```
    public static final int TH32CS_SNAPMODULE = 0x00000008;
```

Note: The process I am enumerating on is already opened with OpenProcess and is valid. The processId is valid as well, and is obtained properly as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping of a pointer as the second argument, while technically correct, requires you to do a lot more overhead with writing it.  It is better to simply put the structure type as an argument. Structures are treated as `.ByReference` when used as function/method arguments, and handle all of the auto-read and write for you.  So if you do this, you can omit your `write()` call:

```java
boolean Module32First(Pointer hSnapshot, WinAPI.MODULEENTRY32 lpme);
boolean Module32Next(Pointer hSnapshot, WinAPI.MODULEENTRY32 lpme);
```

That said, the comment on your write call points to the root cause here:  you need to set the `dwSize` value to the size of the structure.   However, because of the order of initialization of Java Objects, the Structure does not have the information it needs to determine the size when initializing the `dwSize` variable, so this part is not giving you the correct size:

```java
public int dwSize = this.size();
```

To solve this, just declare that variable and set the size later on in the constructor, e.g.,

```java
public static class MODULEENTRY32 extends Structure {
    public int dwSize;
    // other declarations
    
    public MODULEENTRY32() {
        super();
        dwSize = size();
    }   
}
```

In addition your mappings for `szModule` and `szExePath` are incorrect. You've only provided Pointers (a total of 16 bytes) in the structure's memory allocation, but these are fixed length character arrays.  They should be defined:

```java
public char[] szModule = new char[MAX_MODULE_NAME32 + 1];
public char[] szExePath = new char[MAX_PATH];
```

Note the `char[]` mapping is for the Unicode (_W) version of the mapping which is a reasonably safe assumption.

But rather than write yourself, you should use the mappings that already exists in the JNA user-contributed mappings in `jna-platform`.  [The `MODULEENTRY32W` type is already there](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/5ac61611f3c4a74ca3c6ed05c4ffafd7c6070e30/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Tlhelp32.java#L239-L340) (yes it uses `DWORD` so your version is simpler; but you can look at the code to see how they handled the size.) And the `Module32FirstW` and `Module32NextW` functions [are also mapped](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/5ac61611f3c4a74ca3c6ed05c4ffafd7c6070e30/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Tlhelp32.java#L239-L340).  (The W suffix is for wide characters (Unicode) which all modern Windows systems use now.)

Comment: Yeah I just mixed up the words. I meant to say Module32First. I'll edit my post to correct that.

Comment: Hey, so an update. I did exactly as you suggested - the dwSize being initialized in the constructor, and passing in by reference the MODULEENTRY32 Structure. However, after running the program I am still getting "false" returned and the error code 87 from GetLastError.

Comment: Check your mappings. The two strings `szModule` and `szExePath` are fixed length character arrays.  That's `char[]` in Java for unicode.   Why not use the ones already written that I linked?

Comment: Yeah, but I figured it would map to a String but I guess I was wrong. JNA has a "Mappings" readme on their GitHub page, but they only provided common mapping types so I had to guess. I'll try fixing those mappings and let you know. And I decided to do my own structures just for learning purposes and because some mapped functions and structures are not available.

Comment: It was indeed those two fields (`szModule` and `szExePath`) that were causing issues. I initialized them as a new char array with their respective sizes like so: `public char[] szModule = new char[255];` and `public char[] szExePath = new char[260];`. After doing so, it properly enumerates through all modules in the process. Thank you very much!

Comment: Excellent. Don't forget the +1 for the null terminator on `szModule`.

Comment: Yeah, I believe I have that. For some reason, when I convert the char array to a String using `Native.toString(szModule)`, for example, I am getting a bunch of random Chinese characters. I am assuming it's an encoding issue?

Comment: Update, I fixed this issue by encoding the char array to `UTF_16LE`, then decoding it with `ISO_8859_1`. I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but it works at least. Lol.

Comment: You need to use `Native.toWideString(szModule)` to handle UTF16.

Comment: That function does not exist under `Native` for me. I only see `toString`, `toStringList`, etc.

Comment: Oops, sorry was going from memory and thinking of `Pointer.getWideString()`. You were correct to use `Native.toString()` with a `char[]` argument. The already mapped code does exactly this in a helper method. There may be an alignment issue. Can you output `lpme.toString()` and confirm that the `szModule` starts at offset `0x30`?

Comment: And as further troubleshooting, output a portion of the memory dump at that offset: `lpme.getPointer().dump(0x30, 16)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233633/discussion-between-daniel-widdis-and-thisisntsparta).